# Prove that this language is decidable or undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Is the following language decidable?

L = {(M) : M performs at least 100 steps on every accepted input.}

I tried to use reduction from the halting problem, but still no dice.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70747/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42428695/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is decidable.  There is a limited amount of input that any Turing machine could look at in ≤ 100 steps, so you can test a simulation of any given machine $M$ against all of those possibilities.

Comment: Next time, consider waiting until the OP reveals what effort, if any, they expended on solving the problem themselves.